# not able to run mongodb with django 1.4

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am using virtual env. I used these packages to install pymongo.

> https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-1.4
>
> https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangotoolbox/get/tip.tar.gz
>
> https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/tarball/master

this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\virtual\please\lib\site-packages\djangotoolbox\db\base.py", line 94,
in __init__
super(NonrelDatabaseOperations, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Your whole post is formatted as a code block. Please avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

The [django-nonrel 1.4](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-1.4) branch currently has the disclaimer:

```
 "Work in progress 1.4 port, DON'T USE".
```

You should instead use the stable [django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel) branch.